# Кривая кодировка в бд

Tags: кодировка, php

Все данные в бд заносятся в виде крокозябл,уже все проверил что можно было,кодировка базы данных и всех таблицы UTF-8,все имеющиеся файлы тоже в UTF-8, в чем же проблема тогда?

Comment: Опишите более подробно Ваши действия и то как работает программа

Comment: Есть форма и файл php который обрабатывает данные формы и заносит их в бд.

Comment: Соблюдайте указанные правила: [**Ошибка в кодировке**][1] 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/181715/php-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая вероятность, что Вам поможешь после подключение к базе данных, сделать запрос

`mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: Удачи ;-))